# GWT Widget development: combining & overriding CSS

Tags: css, gwt, widget

I've just started learning GWT so my question might be noobish. Tried to find a 'standard' solution but couldn't find it.

I'm developing an AddressWidget. It is implemented as a Composite widget which consist of atomic widgets (*Labels*, *TextBoxes*, *ListBoxes*...) defined in *AddressWidget.ui.xml*. These tiny building blocks should get their CSS from the *common-widgets.css*. The AddressWidget itself should get the default styles from *address-widget.css*.

As this widget will be used on different pages, they should be able to override the styles applied in order to customize the appearance. I.e. the *OrderPage* should apply its own from the *order-page-address-widget.css*, the *ContactDetailsPage* – from the *contact-details-address-widget.css*

How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice - drop this idea. It will be hell to develop and maintain, and I mean it. You will constantly try to figure out which CSS file has to be updated, and then you will have to test every update in multiple places, because an update in one file can mess up with CSS from another file.

Many GWT developers prefer to use [CssResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource) approach to CSS. I've never heard any designer favoring this solution, though.

After years of working with GWT on both the code and design sides, I strongly prefer to use a single CSS file for the entire application. CSS was built for inheritance, and this is what a single file achieves. You can define basic style, like:

```
input {
    height: 24px;
}
```

If you need to change these styles in specific widgets or parts of the application, you can set, for example, "contacts" class on the contacts page/widget, and then add this to your CSS file:

```
.contacts input {
    background: grey;
}
```

The advatantages of this approach:

- easier to enforce consistent look throughout the application
- easier to maintain your CSS, because there is one file to update, and there are no conflicts with CSS defined anywhere else
- it is an approach that most designers understand and know how to use
- it is the easiest solution if you want to create multiple skins or themes for your application
- it is easy to make your CSS adjust to different screen sizes, or define special styles for printing.

Comment: So, if I want to override the CSS for my widget on a specific page I do the following, right?

  <div styleName={myStyles.contacts}>
    <my:AddressWidget ... />
  </div>

I was just wondering how I combine class names in this case because I will use class-inside-class selectors: .contacts .street-address-1.

Comment: You should use "class" instead of "styleName" for HTML elements. StyleName is used for Widgets only.

Comment: Actually, I can't find a way to refer to a class defined in *common.css* from within the AddressWidget.ui.xml. :( If I use styleName="{myStyles.street-address-1}", I see the 'CSS selector street-address-1 is undefined'.

Comment: You can combine classes, but I am not sure why you want one TextBox, ListBox, header, etc., to look different from another. Typically, you want all elements to look the same (height, font, colors, margins, paddings, etc.) throughout the app. If you simply want to set the width, then use 'width' attribute with your widgets.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to use a 'class' instead of 'styleName' for HTML elements. I get it.

But there's still a problem with referencing the widget specific class from AddressWidget.ui.xml

Comment: If you use an external CSS file, you simply set the class name: <div class="contacts">, or <my:AddressWidget styleName="address">

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. Will need to think of organizing the code properly. My team might want to have separate CSS.